# Cannot install mozilla from the Software-Center

Tags: software-center

Trying to install mozilla but I get a error

```
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_37.01+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04_i386.deb 404 Not Found
```

am using a wired connection to modem as my wireless is playing up too.

any ideas?

Comment: I think someone, or you has changed the content on `/etc/apt/source.list`

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't know it, the latest version of Firefox from the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 12.04 is Firefox 40 and you have a software source in your sources.list file that is adding Firefox 37 to your software sources. This is very irregular. If the default version of Firefox in the Ubuntu Software Center is more up-to-date, you should normally install that version instead. Unless you have a compelling reason to install Firefox 37 on your system, you should remove the line that refers to `http://security.ubtuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_37.01+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04_i386.deb` from your sources.list file, run `sudo apt-get update` to update your software sources, and stay with the latest version of Firefox from the default Ubuntu repositories.

---

Otherwise you need to correct the misspelling in `http://security.ubtuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_37.01+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04_i386.deb`

1. Use the terminal text editor program nano to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Open the terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. In sources.list replace this string:

   ```
   http://security.ubtuntu.com
   ```

   with this string to correct the spelling error (ubuntu was misspelled):

   ```
   http://security.ubuntu.com
   ```
3. The instructions for using nano are always displayed at the bottom of the page. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location. Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.
4. Update the software sources to get rid of the `Failed to fetch ... 404 Not Found` error:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
5. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and try to install the package again.

Answer (score 1):

It was typo on `/etc/apt/source.list` so fix it :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Click "Search for and Replace the text"

[image]

Fill "Search for" with ubtuntu, whereas "Replace with" ubuntu.

[image]

And click "Replace All". Save the file then

This action require an update, so... :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Open software center and try download firefox again

**Terminal ways**

Use sed to filtering and transforming text, this thing useful if people too lazy to open gedit and write something. In your case it would be :

```
sudo sed -i 's/ubtuntu/ubuntu/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

And then do a simple source update :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate of my previously posted answer. Was this intentional?

Comment: Nope I didnt trying to copy your answer, It take a long time to capture screenshot